# Concatenate two arrays of different dimensions numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of the form np.array([1,2,3])) I want to concatenate them so I get:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

and it also has to work when there is a numpy array of the form [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and another one [7,8,9] and I want to get:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I tried np.concatenate but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: What error did you get?  Describe your array dimensions, input and desired.

Comment: I kept getting [1,2,3,4,5,6] instead. The array dimensions change, the only constant is the length of the inside arrays (in the examples 3)

Comment: You forgot to read the `concatenate` docs. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vstack` for this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
c = np.array([7,8,9])

d = np.vstack((a,b))

e = np.vstack((d, c))

print(d)
print(e)
```

Gives:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]    

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
```

Comment: Though to use `concatenate` the 1d inputs have to first have a new leading axis added.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for the comment, and yes, it wasn't setting the axis (as I mistakenly said) but adding a leading axis. I just removed the concatenate comment since it didn't help the answer and doing `concatenate` seems a distraction in this case.